# ¿Cuál sería la diferencia entre llave primaria compuesta y un índice único compuesto? ¿Cómo saber cuál usar?

Tags: mysql, sql

Si defino una tabla mediante un llave primaria compuesta:

#### Caso 1:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabla_pk 
(
    col_idx1               INT NOT NULL,
    col_idx2               INT NOT NULL,
    col_int                INT NOT NULL,
    col_varchar            VARCHAR(100),  
    CONSTRAINT tabla_pk_PK01 PRIMARY KEY (col_idx1,col_idx2)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Y otra tabla mediante un índice único compuesto:

#### Caso 2:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabla_unique 
(
    col_idx1               INT NOT NULL,
    col_idx2               INT NOT NULL,
    col_int                INT NOT NULL,
    col_varchar            VARCHAR(100),  
    CONSTRAINT tabla_unique_AK01 UNIQUE (col_idx1,col_idx2)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Los datos parecen funcionar igual.

Sin embargo ante situaciones en las que quiero que no haya dos combinaciones de `col_idx1` y `col_idx2` iguales no me queda claro si debo optar por una llave primaria compuesta (caso 1)  o un índice único compuesto (caso 2).

Sin caer en meras opiniones:

- **¿qué criterios podría seguir para decidir cuál usar?** o,
- **¿hay otra posibilidad diferente a los casos 1 o 2?**

Comment: El único criterio realmente esencial para definir una `PK`, simple o compuesta, es si la columna o la combinación de estas es el mejor mecanismo para identificar unívocamente a la fila. Si no lo hace o hay una columna o columnas mejores para identificar la fila, entonces no es una `PK`, tan simple como eso. Al menos eso entiendo yo.

Comment: A menos que sepas muy bien lo que estás haciendo, evita usar llaves primarias compuestas. Incluso más, evita usar llaves foráneas compuestas. Es una abstracción innecesaria en el 90% de los casos y rio abajo te puede complicar todo, máxime si el día de mañana otro desarrollador tiene que hacerse cargo de mantener la app o la BBDD. Usa una PK normal, autoincremental, y luego le pones una llave única a la tupla que mencionas. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Todas las tablas deberían tener una clave primaria, que es, a su vez, única. A partir de ahí, depende de las necesidades que tengas valdrá la pena usar una clave primaria compuesta, aprovechando que es única, o una sencilla y dejar la validación de valores únicos mediante un índice único o por programación

Por ejemplo, hay frameworks, como *Laravel* con *Eloquent*, que trabajan por defecto con claves primarias sencillas, no admiten compuestas, así que te verías obligado a tener una columna que hiciera de clave primaria y definir un índice único para las columnas que lo requieran. Otras librerías, como *Hibernate*, son más flexibles a la hora de trabajar y sí permiten tener tanto claves primarias sencillas como compuestas así que depende mucho de tus necesidades

Para los ejemplos que has puesto, el caso 1 ya estaría bien si quieres (y puedes) usar una clave primaria compuesta pero en el caso 2 habría que añadir una columna id que fuera la clave primaria de la tabla

Answer (score 0):

Te puedo compartir que estamos hablando de cosas distintas, tal como ya se comentó, las tablas deben (o deberían, para evitar un infiernitis) tener una llave primaria, independientemente de si hay o no restricciones Unique.

Por lo regular las llaves compuestas se utilizan cuando estamos hablando de relaciones N:N entre tablas, que si en tu caso es así, no habría problema.

Como punto final y creo que es lo que causa ruido, por la formulación de la pregunta, pareciera dar la impresión de que quieres utilizar un intento de violación a la PK o al Unique constraint para asegurar la no duplicidad de los registros, lo cual sin buscar que suene a opinión sino a un criterio de buenas prácticas: no es recomendable, sería una analogía a "hacer validaciones con try/catch y buscar mejores opciones para validar en el catch", dicho lo anterior, este criterio de buenas prácticas sería aplicable a antes de la pregunta, por lo que cuesta trabajo responder.